# Digraph without "immediately isomorphic" vertices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, posets, directed-graphs

Say that a digraph $(V,E)$ is *reducible* if there exist $x,y\in V$ with $x\ne y$ and such that for all $z\in V$, $(x,z)\in E\leftrightarrow(y,z)\in E$ and $(z,x)\in E\leftrightarrow(z,y)\in E$. It is clear that a reducible digraph has a non-trivial automorphism (swapping $x$ and $y$ and fixing the rest), but the inverse is not necessarily true.

For some applications elsewhere, I'm interested in "irreducible" digraphs and especially "irreducible" posets. Now, (insert usual disclaimer about not being an expert), do these already have a (potentially better) name? and if yes, where have they been treated?

Comment: *Twin-free* might be the term you're after.

Comment: By "where could I find them" do you mean finding actual (small?) examples, or finding in some other sense?

Comment: Very small examples exist. The smallest poset with a nontrivial automorphism but no twin elements has 4 elements: the disjoint union of two 2-element chains. If you require connected, the smallest such poset has 5 elements (the previous and an adjoined bottom element).  So what kind of examples do you desire?

Comment: Graphs (undirected) with the property that no two distinct vertices have the same neighborhood have several names: point-determining, R-thin, mating type, and M-graphs. See, e.g., https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2010.03.009. I don't know that the analogous digraphs have been studied.

Comment: Thank you, "twin-free" seems indeed to be good terminology, as do the suggestions by Ira.
By "where could I find them?" I meant finding references to the terminology, not finding the graphs themselves, sorry for the ambiguity which I have now removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide a conclusion here (summing up the comments): *twin-free* seems to be the best and, dare I say, standard terminology; two points as in my question would then be called *twins*.  Otherwise, *point-determining*, *R-thin*, or *mating-type* have been used to denote the same property.